# Javascript function returns promise $$state

Tags: javascript, promise

This could be a potential duplicate but I couldn't get any solution working so far , so I had to write it down.
I have a function that is making an http request and doing some more things like-

```
function getData(){
   return $http.get('/'+ 'somedata')
   .then(somefunctionA)
   .then(somefunctionB)
}
```

When I am calling this function and using then waiting for promise to be resolved it is still not giving me any data.Rather its printing the data after this function.

```
function callgetData(){
   return getData()
   .then(function (data from getData){
      console.log(datafromgetData)
   }).catch (function (error){
       throw error
   })
}
```

Could you please help and excuse my naive-ness?I am new to JS.

Thanks

Comment: your `.then` console logs the data, then doesn't have a return statement ... which is equivalent to `return undefined` - `you need to return datafromgetData` in your `.then` so that the promise returned by `callgetData` will have the correct value

Comment: "*Rather its printing the data after this function.*" - well that's what `console.log` is supposed to do. What is unexpected about this? What else do you want to do?

Comment: "*`.catch (function (error){
       throw error
   })`*" does nothing useful. Omit it and the code will work the same.

Comment: @JaromandaX even though I return , it doesn't show promise in resolved state.It still shows state=0.

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX sorted this out - returning the datafromgetData worked but to actually use the value returned I need to perform my logic within the .then of the funciton that was calling callgetData -                                                     function thatcallgetData(){return callgetData().then (use the value returned )

Comment: well, that's how Promises work